# Mule Data Mapper is Pay in Prodcution

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule ESB and I just want to clarify one doubt whether the use of Mule Data Mapper is Free Production Environment or not. Please share some link based on the use of Mule Data Mapper.

Comment: No. Ask a question that is not completely offtopic, and lots of people will help.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference), the DataMapper is exclusive to Mule Enterprise Edition (the non-free version). You can, however, experiment with it in the Community Edition:

> Full DataMapper functionality is exclusive to the Mule Enterprise
>   runtimes.
>
> But we want to give you a taste of what you’re missing! Experiment
>   with DataMapper in the Studio visual editor in a project that uses a
>   Community Runtime to evaluate this powerful tool that maps data
>   through a graphical interface. Not only can you develop your
>   full-featured DataMapper application with a Community runtime, you can
>   preview your data mappings as well.
>
> However, to RUN your application and observe DataMapper in a test or
>   production environment, you must run the application with an
>   Enterprise runtime. Learn more about Changing Runtimes in Studio.